# Obtener datos de un input usando Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

estoy tratando de obtener el valor de un input, no quiero usar un boton y quiero obtener el valor cuando se deje de seleccionar la caja de texto en la que se están ingresando los datos, alguna idea de como poder empezar??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `blur`de jquery, básicamente esta función se utiliza cuando se quita el "foco" a un elemento. Ejemplo:

```js
$( "#input" ).blur(function() {
      alert( "Se ha quitado el foco del elemento");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Has clic en el input y luego en un espacio en blanco:
<input id="input" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo funcionara si el input ya tiene un valor al cargar la pagina

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 cedula = $("#iddelinput").val();
  alert(cedula);
)}
```